# Sylow p- subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

I am new to the theory of "Sylow p-subgroups", and I am stuck at one point.

My book gives the following definition of a Sylow p-subgroup:

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^km$ where $k>=1$ and p is some  prime number such that p does not divide m.Then a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^k$ is called a Sylow p-subgroup.

What i wanted to ask is, that, is it necessary that in a Sylow p-subgroup,which has an order of $p^k$ every element also has its order as some power of $p$.

For example, in a group $G$ of order $56$ a sylow-7 subgroup means that it is a subgroup of order $7$ but at the same time does it also mean that every element of that group also has an order of $7$?

I am confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Sylow $p$-subgroup every element will have order a power of $p$ by [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29). In the whole group $G$ we can still have elements of other orders.

Comment: Thanks! i was missing such a teeny tiny point!

Answer (score 0):

No: The product of cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ has a 2-subgroup containing an element of order 4.